# Wildfly in intelliJ 12.1

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly-8, intellij-12

Is there a way I can configure Wildfly 8 in IntelliJ 12.1? I'm getting this error message:

[image: wildfly in intellij 12.1]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with IntelliJ IDEA 13 and it works as listed at:

http://planet.jboss.org/post/intellij_idea_13_java_ee_7_and_wildfly_tech_tip_4

You may have to update the version of IntelliJ.

Also check out a screencast at: http://blog.arungupta.me/2014/04/wildfly8-and-intellij-idea-screencast/

Comment: Apparently yes, unless somebody from IntelliJ team can comment.